# jquery delegated keyup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegation

I am creating a slideshow that is appended on document. I am hiding the body and appending the slideshow outside of the body element. I wan't to close the slideshow on escape button.

The structure of the page is the following:

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <body style="display: none;"></body>
    <div class="slideshow"></div>
</html>
```

I have tried things like:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.slideshow', function( e ){
alert("Here");
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        alert("Escape");
    };
});
```

If i change `keyup` to be on `click` then it can show an alert `Here` , but it does not delegate keyup. Disregard the esc alert, if i add alert before it also doesn't show, so the problem is not in escape key code.

Comment: Your `slideshow` div is outside the `body` tag.

Comment: Yes i know, what should i do then?

Comment: it's not valid then if it's outside the body tag.

Comment: if you use this for practice, try 'click' instead of keyup, reason has been given by @bingjie2680

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can't do this. It is because the `document` has no way to determine that `keyup` event is triggered from `slideshow`, unless the slideshow contains any input fields and you type something in.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the div by 'input' tag which gives you an input box, so when you type in something, the alert will then be triggered.

```
<body style="display: block;">
    <input class="slideshow"/>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshow').keyup(function (e) {
        alert("Here");
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            alert("Escape");
        };
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8jNx/)